# grails 3.3.8 generated controller fails to create objects

Tags: grails

I have a User domain object with the usual fields (name, password etc)

I generated the views and conltroller using:

grails generate-all User

The generaged UserController has this:

```
 def create() {
      respond new User(params)
 }
```

When I run the app, and click on create user button, I get this error:

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error
URI
/user/create
Class
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException
Message
null
Caused by
No such property: controller for class: gi.dam.desk.core.User
Around line 23 of grails-app/controllers/gi/dam/desk/admin/UserController.groovy
20:     }
21:
22:     def create() {
23:          respond new User(params)
24:     }
```

If I debug the app, and look at the contents of "params", its:

```
controller: user
format: null
action: create
```

it seems odd that this would be passed to creating a domain object.  Either way, it fails.

If I change the code thusly:

```
 def create() {
      respond new User()
 }
```

It gets further - it creates the user, but fails on the redirect after.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like your `User` class is not being recognized as a domain class.  I can tell that because the `Map` constructor that we add to domain classes will ignore entries in the `Map` that don't have corresponding properties in the class.  The error you are seeing is what comes out of the default Groovy `Map` constructor, which is why I think your `User` class is not being recognized as a domain class.

Confirm that your `User` domain class is defined in `grails-app/domain/gi/dam/desk/core/User.groovy` and if the problem is still happening, verify that the problem occurs when running the app from the command line `./gradlew bootRun`.  This will rule out a number of things you might be doing that relate to an IDE being improperly configured.

Comment: The `create` method at https://github.com/jeffbrown/johnlittledomain/blob/570b2b3e1c49ab89288b459d507df8ef40e90058/grails-app/controllers/gi/dam/desk/core/UserController.groovy#L22 works fine.

Comment: If you can share a project which demonstrates the behavior you describe, it would be trivial to troubleshoot.